# My postgres has a strange userDB as superuser. I can't remove this user

Tags: linux, postgresql

Yesterday, my postgres had 4 superuser like shown in the first image, but today it has a strange user (`cloudsqladmin_user`) as superuser and the other users have lost the attributes. I don't know what going on? I use Postgres 15.

Yesterday:

[image: Yesterday]

Today:

[image: Today]

Comment: There is almost certainly no innocent explanation for this.  You have been hacked, and the hackers are trying to prevent you from taking back control by removing superuser from all the other accounts.

Comment: If you need to censor the user names (I don't see the point) you should do a better job.  It isn't hard to guess what those are based on the visible parts of the ascender and descenders and a bit of baseline.

Comment: Are you running Postgres on GCP?